# New to Python trying to manipulate a cashflow data from yahoo finance

Tags: pandas, dataframe

So I am returning this cashflow dataframe. I want to be able to search it for a particular year, as well as pull a specific row ('free cash flow'). Would love any recommendations:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOY61.png)

I Tried this:
free_cash_flow_desired_year = cashflow.loc[cashflow.index.year == baseline, 'Free Cash Flow']

but got an error

Comment: You want to filter columns, use `cashflow.filter(like=baseline)`

Comment: what if I also want to pull out just the row for free cash flow?

Comment: `cashflow.filter(like=baseline).loc['Free Cash Flow']`

Comment: Even with these updates, I am still getting the same results as the picture above

Comment: Have you assigned the output of the above command? This is not modifying the original dataframe.